# Access denied for user, using password 'NO' only outside of public_html

Tags: php, mysql, bluehost

I'm trying to run a cron job outside of public_html. This works inside public_html just fine but once I move it outside (for security) and let the cron execute my PHP, I get a PHP Warning:  mysql_query() Access denied for user 'XYZ'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

```
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user_name', 'password_includes_*$?');
$db_select = mysql_select_db('database_name', $db);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO resource (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('$_var1', '$_var2', '$_var3')");
```

Comment: can you try with `mysql_query("INSERT INTO ... '$_var3')", $db);` ?

Comment: This did not work. It says I'm using NO password, but it's there in single quotes...

Comment: Check the value of $db_select It is supposed to be a boolean.